# .Net CLR Unloading vs shutdown?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, clr, appdomain

> What Causes Finalize Methods to Be Called ?

2 answers( of 4 ) to this question are :

- `The CLR is unloading an AppDomain` When an AppDomain unloads, the CLR considers
  nothing in the AppDomain to be a root, and a garbage collection consisting of
  all generations is performed.
- `The CLR is shutting down` The CLR shuts down when a process terminates normally
  (as opposed to an external shutdown via Task Manager, for example).

I assume that `The CLR is unloading an AppDomain` is when the program (console [exe] for example) is being closed ( by pressing close / normal end of program)

What about `The CLR is shutting down` ? *continuing the [Exe] program analogy above :*

- what does it mean ?  How can I *ShutDown CLR*  ...?
- [in the IIS world] does it mean IIS reset ?

please, can I have small explanation ?

Comment: don't think there is any kind of *shut down* of `CLR`, most probabbly it's just a way of say/thinking about unload....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The AppDomain is a more granular unit than the Process. A Process can can have multiple AppDomain instances, each of which can be unloaded separately.

The CLR shutdown is the process terminating.

The AppDomain unloading is each AppDomain separately.

(although I would not personally guarantee, without checking the documentation, that all finalizers etc are executed in either case)

As an example, I use multiple AppDomain instances in a long-running self-updating windows service; when new versions are detected it pulls down the new binaries, spawns a new AppDomain, gets it running, switches future operations to the new AppDomain, and unloads the old AppDomain (when running operations have completed).

Comment: +1 what actually I was thinking about, but wasn't sure to make a post :)

Comment: whan Im running simple console application....it has 1 AppDomain and 1 process....aint it ?

Comment: @Royi yes a simple console exe has one Process and one AppDomain

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from spawning another AppDomain inside a console application though.

Comment: *(although I would not personally guarantee, without checking the documentation, that all finalizers etc are executed in either case)* - this is the main question which those are the answers.... so Finilize DOES run at the sutdown... the only time which he dont is when finilizer Thread is stuck in a loop or it takes more than 2 seconds so he kills the whole process....( c# via clr book)

Comment: @MarcGravell: the memory limit applied on .NET binaries,I mean I can not run on 32bit system more then approx. 1.2GB of working set. Is it appied for `process` or `domain` ?

Comment: @tigran process - although you should be able to get a bit higher than that. Have you tried the 3gb switch?

Comment: @MarcGravell: as far as a know it's valid for Windows Server family and not desktop OS, am I wrong ?

Comment: +1 for the self-updating service! way too few people know about the awesome appdomain spawning and unloading at runtime

Comment: @MarcGravell Can you please provide a small sample where 1 console application has more than 1 appDomain ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: [How to create and use AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173140(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: @Tigran ...ok thanks....but why would i ever want x appDomains in my process ? if 1 falls down , the whole system wont function correctly....so ?

Comment: cause you can *unload* domain, more or less like you can run a separate executable, make some heavy calculation/allocate memory, return result to launcher and go away from the memory. The same is for domains. Infact in order to be able to pass a variable between domains you need to use IPC methods, just like if completely different process.

Comment: @Royi I already included an example in the answer - versioning without stopping. Isolation is another.

Comment: @MarcGravell: mine was doubt, actually. I just run on very comlicated memory issue on my current project where we use a CAD system completely written in C#, kernel too (don't blame me it wasn't my choice :)), so would try it immediately on Monday :) I remember to read in some blogs that it's available *only* for WindowsServer.. bah, will have a look by the way. Thanks !

Comment: @Tigran here's a CAD example talking XP and Vista, so seems desktop too: http://dwf.blogs.com/beyond_the_paper/2009/04/enabling-3gb-switch-on-windows-vista.html